# How to protect the azure blob storage urls from being retrieved by anyone using developer tools

Tags: azure, url, html5-video, blob, azure-blob-storage

I have to save images/videos in azure blobs and then use them in my site. After doing some research I found that you have to include the blob url in the href tag for the image/video to be retrieved from azure.

However anybody could open the site page and get that blob url and misuse it. Also the site has user authentication, hence only after login should the user be able to see that image/video on the site page.

Is there any other way of retrieving blobs from azure? Or any other solution to the url being openly visible in developer tools?

I am currently using an azure emulator with Visual Studio.

[image: An example of a test site which is showing a video stored as a blob]

Comment: There's a couple of ways you could go about this. One is to not have the Blobs be publicly available and by retrieving them through a backend service (could be an Azure function). Example: `api/images/uniquename`. Another would be to use a Shared Access Key which has read-only access to only the images needed.

Comment: @rickvdbosch I'm not sure if 1st solution would work. Instead of using blob URL I will use the API URL and still be able to access the blob unless I protect the API calls as well. 2nd solution will not completely prevent this situation but can control it to a large extent with short lived SAS tokens and proper IP ACLing.

Comment: @GauravMantri I know the first solution works since I've used it like this before :) Especially with Azure Functions you can create a backend service like this really fast. I had the function use the Azure SDK to retrieve files from blob storage and return them to be used in the frontend.

Comment: @rickvdbosch Now you've made me curious :). I don't think your explanation would fit in comments. Would you mind providing an answer with details? That would be super helpful.

Comment: @rickvdbosch would appreciate if you could elaborate further :)

Comment: @GauravMantri - what do you mean by SAS tokens and IP ACLing? Is this something that is being done by other sites with data on azure? Would appreciate if you could share more :)

Comment: SAS -> Shared Access Signature. You may find these blog posts helpful: https://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/13/revisiting-windows-azure-shared-access-signature/, https://gauravmantri.com/2015/10/12/azure-storage-shared-access-signature-enhancements/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've recreated an Azure Function that implements the first scenario I mentioned. The Blob URL inside the storage account was not exposed, and the container and everything in it is set to be private. Since I don't know your authentication scheme I skipped that for now, but you could secure this in a number of ways.

There's a few shortcuts in this code, but you'll get the general idea. Here's the code:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "files/{id}")]
    HttpRequest req, string id, TraceWriter log)
{
    var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("UseDevelopmentStorage=true");
    var client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    var container = client.GetContainerReference("sitecontent");
    var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(id);

    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(stream);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
            new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

    return result;
}
```

I've tested it by referencing it from an HTML file like this:

```
<img src="http://localhost:7071/api/files/techdays2017.jpg" alt="Me at TechDays 2017" />
```

The image I used was 267KB, response times of the Function were all < 200 ms when testing locally using the Storage Emulator.

Comment: I'm not sure how this will prevent the misuse. I can take this URL and put it in browser's address bar and I will be able to access the blob. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Well, the full url to the blob in storage is no longer visible, blobs don't need to be public anymore, and the Function can be secured so the file is only downloaded when a user is logged in.

Comment: Aah...I see your point. But yes, this would require the Function to be secured otherwise keeping the blob private is not going to help.

Comment: We kinda did the same over here as well by the time I saw ur answer :) Thanks a tonne though :)

Comment: This is very wrong answer, simplest and correct answer would be to use shared access signature, there is absolutely no need to reroute network calls through azure functions. Also this does not support partial download with progress etc and not at all a valid for delivering video from azure blobs.

Comment: @akashkava We could still paste the URL that’s generated with the SAS and download the content. Is there a workaround to prevent unauthorized downloads for video files. I have been facing this problem for a while now :(

Comment: @Illep SAS Url has timestamp, you can set timestamp to expire in 15 seconds, SAS Url was designed for this specific purpose. You can simply generate the URL on every call on your server, so your server only issues redirect url that is valid only for 15 seconds.

Comment: @AkashKava What if I am playing a video of about 30mins long. How should I handle this scenario when the SAS url expires every 30seconds ? If I fetch another URL will the video play continuously ?

Comment: @Illep There are various ways you can do it,

Comment: @Illep It will still work, because browsers stream video in parts, few megabytes, not whole movie, so for first 10 seconds, browser will fetch source url from your server, your server will send SAS URL and browser will connect to azure and it will stream for 10 seconds, after 10 seconds, again it will come to your server for new SAS URL, and you just deliver new one. By limiting server only to send SAS URL, you will reduce bandwidth, allow CDN to be in between and improve the user performance.

Comment: @AkashKava is it that I have a timer code implemented in my front end angular app and request a new SAS token from the server is this a good way to implement this feature ?

Comment: You don’t need timer, browser does it automatically

Comment: Hi @rickvdbosch, great solution! But, just a question... when you call this AF endpoint, are you every time downloading the image from the blob via this line: "await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(stream);" ?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if the question is valid, but another very simple approach could be

1. Use a custom domain with your storage endpoint
2. Make your blobs and containers private
3. using backend infra, generate a Shared Access Token which should be valid only for short duration.
4. Use the SAS to generate blob urls.

Incase you need to hide the structure alltogether, all the steps could be used in conjugation with functions as mentioned in answer by @rick.

One thing to understand is that video stream needs to go to browser player, so there cannot be any perfect plan. The above option also will just time bound the access. There could be some other options like message layer encryption by which the server sends in encrypted content and it will be decrypted at runtime You need to have some custom player functionality as well as this could incur higher charges on server side..

Even this will not user from pirating video if he has skillset and high motivation, but can somehow make it difficult and that should be driving point here.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1