# Is it possible to use Azure Blob Storage on a website that has no authentication?

Tags: file-upload, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I need to create a way for anyone who visits my website to upload an image to an Azure Blob Container. The website will have [input validations on the file](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Input_Validation_Cheat_Sheet.html#file-upload-validation).

I've considered using an Azure Function to write the validated file to the Blob Container, but I can't seem to find a way to do this without exposing the Function URL to the world (similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50507959/how-to-protect-the-azure-blob-storage-urls-from-being-retrieved-by-anyone-using).

I would use a System-Assigned Managed Identity (SAMI) to authenticate the Function to the Storage account, but because of this, anyone could take the Function URL and bypass the validations and upload.

**How is this done in the real world?**

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the user uploads a file via an HTTP POST call to your server, which validates it. You would like to use an Azure Function to then upload the validated file to the Blob Storage.

In this case, you can restrict the access to the Azure Function; so that it can only be called from your server's IP. This way the users cannot reach that Function. This can be done via the networking settings, and [is available on all Azure Function plans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-networking-options?tabs=azure-cli).

You could also consider implementing the validation logic within the Azure Function.

Finally (perhaps I should have started with this), if you are only considering writing an Azure Function to upload data to a Storage Account, you should perhaps first consider using the Blob Service REST API, specifically the [PUT Blob endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob). There are also official Storage Account SDKs for different languages/ecosystems that you could use to do this.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Clarification: User clicks an "upload" button on website. User selects a local file to upload. User clicks "Submit" button. THIS TRIGGERS THE AZURE FUNCTION TO WRITE TO BLOB CONTAINER. There is no intermediate step of uploading file to web server. How does this affect your recommendation?

Comment: Its not that I have any issue using an SDK to write files to Azure Blob Storage. I have an issue with `right click`, `view source`, and seeing the SAS token or client ID / secret in the HTML. I need to interact with Azure Blob Storage in an internet-facing website.

Comment: When you says SAS token, do you mean the one to the Storage Account? I don't understand why this would be exposed in the function URL. The connection string to the Storage Account is defined as an application setting inside the Azure Function App. Unless I'm missing something, there is no way for a user to see it given the Function URL.

Answer (score 1):

•   Since, you are using an Azure function default generic URL on your website for uploading blobs with no authentication, I would suggest you to please **create an ‘A’ host record for your function app**. Considering that you have a website, you may be having a custom domain for your website to be unique and as you might be having a custom domain, **the custom domain’s DNS records must be hosted on a public DNS server**. Thus, similarly, on the same public DNS server, you will have to **create an ‘A’ host record for the function app and assign it the same public IP address that is shown and assigned in Azure**. This will **ensure that your public DNS server has an active DNS resolver for the function app globally and then ensure to create a ‘CNAME’ record for your default generic Azure function app URL with the same URL as the alias in the DNS records and the ‘A’ host record as the assigned value in it**.

In this way, whenever, **any anonymous person visits your website and tries to upload an image, he will be shown the function app URL as ‘abc.xyz.com’ and not the generic Azure function app URL thus successfully ensuring that your objective is achieved**.

[image: Azure function custom domain configuration]

•   Once the above said has been done, then **publish the new ‘CNAME’ record created in the public DNS server as your function app URL**. This will not ***expose the generic Azure function app URL and mask it as well as ensure that it is secured since you will be uploading an SSL/TLS certificate for the website to be HTTPS protected in the function app workspace*** itself as shown below in the snapshot: -

[image: SSL certificate configuration]

For more information, kindly refer the below documentation link: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-custom-domain***